# Choosing the right call for Plugin to dynamically generate JSON-LD (vue.js,nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, page-lifecycle

I am tryin to create an FAQ component in Nuxt.js that dynamically generates JSON-LD scripts for structured data. The structured data represents an FAQ page with questions and answers.https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/faqpage

My current Problem is that it's called too early I think and the content of my component is not attached.

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const metaLdScripts = []

    nuxtApp.$addLdScript = (script) => metaLdScripts.push(script)

    const attachLdScripts = () => {
        const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]

        const scriptTag = document.createElement('script')

        scriptTag.type = 'application/ld+json'
        scriptTag.text = `{
            '@context': 'https://schema.org',
            '@type': 'FAQPage',
            mainEntity: ${JSON.stringify(metaLdScripts)},
        }`

        head.appendChild(scriptTag)
    }
    
    nuxtApp.hook('page:finish', () => {
        attachLdScripts()
    })
})
```

This plugins is called in a different component and it should be filled with it's data.

```
<template>
    <div v-editable="blok" class="c-item c-item-collapse">
        <button @click="toggleCollapse" class="c-item-collapse__header">
            <div class="c-item-collapse__title">
                <ui-headline size="0" :tagName="blok.title_headline">
                    {{ blok.title }}
                </ui-headline>
            </div>
            <div class="c-item-collapse__actions">
                <ui-icon v-if="!isCollapsed" icon="circle-minus" />
                <ui-icon v-else icon="circle-plus" />
            </div>
        </button>
        <div></div>

        <div v-show="!isCollapsed" class="c-item-collapse__content">
            <StoryblokComponent
                v-for="blok in blok.items"
                :key="blok._uid"
                :blok="blok"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const { $addLdScript } = useNuxtApp()

const isCollapsed = ref(true)

function toggleCollapse() {
    isCollapsed.value = !isCollapsed.value
}

const { blok } = defineProps({ blok: Object })

onMounted(() => {
    $addLdScript({
        '@type': 'Question',
        name: blok.title,
        acceptedAnswer: {
            '@type': 'Answer',
            text: blok.items.map(
                (item) => item.body?.content[0]?.content[0]?.text
            ),
        },
    })
})
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.c-item-collapse {
    @apply p-8 bg-white rounded-xl md:rounded;

    .ui-section--bg-white & {
        // box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px #22222214;
        @apply bg-gray-light;
    }

    &__header {
        @apply flex justify-between items-center text-graphite w-full;
    }

    &__actions {
        @apply flex items-center;
    }

    &__title {
        @apply font-black font-barlow text-left text-sm md:text-base;
    }

    &__content {
        @apply pt-4 text-xs md:text-base;
    }
}

.c-item-collapse + .c-item-collapse {
    @apply mt-2 md:mt-4;
}
</style>
```

Output:

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">{
            '@context': 'https://schema.org',
            '@type': 'FAQPage',
            mainEntity: [],
        }</script>
```

I am using a custom plugin because I don't want to have several application/ld+json script tags in the Head for the Item-crawler component since it's all going to be FAQPages and kinda mess up the Google Rich Text Result schema. I tried using the https://github.com/ymmooot/nuxt-jsonld/blob/master/README.md calling the module in different render times, but that didn't work. It still makes separate script tags for each item crawler component in the Page.

I am pretty sure the problem is the timing. After everything is rendered the plugin should be called and executed, I think just setting a timer would be quite some bad practice Ig.I tried nearly all lifecycle hooks presented in the vue docs.

Comment: Why don't you try the [nuxt-jsonld](https://github.com/ymmooot/nuxt-jsonld/blob/master/README.md) module? I used it successfully in Nuxt 2 project, but I still have to test it in a Nuxt 3 project.

Comment: @learntheropes thanks for the input, I will try using that module this week.

Comment: @learntheropes Okay so I did and I am sorry think I didn't make clear why I was using a custom plugin. It's because I don't want to have several application/ld+json script tags in the Head for the Item-crawler component since it's all going to be FAQPages and kinda mess up the Google Rich Text Result schema. I tried calling the module in different render times but that didn't work. It still makes separate script tags for each item crawler component in the Page. Do you have any other suggestions?